# How to stick an element to the same position on page scroll?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering how to force a DOM element to stay at the same position when the user scrolls the page. Let's say, in the bottom-right corner of the page. I need that element to be the same visible no matter what is the current page's scroll position. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need some CSS:

```
#theElement {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wemBK/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position):

```css
#myelem{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position:fixed;` for this. Fixed is a rule that the div needs to stay in that position even when the page is scrolling

**CSS**

```
.div
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably confusing css position absolute with position fixed.  What you probably want is position fixed.  No jQuery required.